# how to structure REST api with multiple POST endpoints

Tags: node.js, rest, api

I have an api that allows you to create a user using multiple POST endpoints

For example, you can create a user by:
1) posting a "profile" object
2) posting a email address object

These methods are handled by separate controller actions

I wanted to know how to design the api endpoints so it follows REST conventions with nouns, no verbs, etc

eg, what should I add to the below uri to communicate that there are multiple POST endpoints

> POST /users

eg:

endpoint one accepts:

> {
>     profile: {}
>   }

endpoint two accepts:

> {
>    email: "" 
>   }

Comment: Aren't you actually creating either a profile or an email address, having the side effect of creating a user?

Comment: No, essentially, I am create a different a user, but the input data to the endpoint is different.  eg, profile object looks very different to email object.  I added an example of the input object to my question above

Comment: Why can't a single endpoint accept either?